# How to change initialFrameForViewController in UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I have the feeling it's possible that somehow, the View Controller can define it's own `initialFrameForViewController` rather than I just write down a CGRectMake in my `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning` delegate method.

But I didn't find anything about it. If someone is an expert about this stuff ?